# Apache Axis2 and Spring3 how to use @Autowired

Tags: apache, spring, apache-axis, autowired

I haven't used Apache Axis since my 1.x days so I am little rusty here. My question is this.... How do I go about using the @Autowired annotation in my Apache Axis2 service endpoint class? Is this possible? I did some google searching and have yet to find anything conclusive. I am using Apache Axis2 version 1.5.1 and Spring 3.0.3. I just want to autowire up a simple DAO into my Web Service endpoint. I wouldn't think that would be so hard. I have already configured my applicationContext.xml and tested my DAO in a simple DBunit JUnit test case so it works fine. I can also Autowire up my Spring bean in my JUnit test. In my WAR I have configured my web.xml to use the org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener. This works fine and I can see when I deploy the war that the applicationCOntext is loaded up. Now how do I wire this up so I can use @Autowired in my Apache Axis2 service endpoint class?

Thanks for any help in advance!
Kyle

Answer (score 4):

Resolved my own issue. Jsst needed to have my Service Endpoint class simply extend the  SpringBeanAutowiringSupport class.